# Retonar uma #div via arquivo PHP jo Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Meu problema é,
Tenho uma tabela que exibe as informações que tem no banco dos dados cadastrados informações no index. E no index tem a opção de adicionar um novo registro (Modal Ajax), no arquivo `editaagenda.php` tem todos formulários (CRUD) quando retorna sucesso `.done()` no ajax eu chamo o `editaagenda.php` para atualizar a tabela hmtl com as informação atualizadas preciso exibir a lista os dados no index sem precisar dar reflesh na página.

E a única forma que me veio a mente foi após inserção pegar o arquivo com o $.get e jogar na div .read_content do index no lugar do outro para atualizar sem reflesh.

Meu código:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'add-data.php',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: dados,
        type: 'post'
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#addfrm').modal('hide');
        $('#frm')[0].reset();
        $.get("editaagenda.php?#read_content", {}, function (data, status) {
            $(".read_content").html(data);
        });
```

Seria esse forma para que ele retorne apenas a parte do código no arquivo `editaagenda.php` onde tem a div com id="read_content",
porém dessa forma que fiz ele está retornando toda pagina ao invés de apenas a Div com id="read_content".

Comment: Por que não modifica o PHP para retornar apenas o que você precisa? Isso diminuirá o payload da sua comunicação e fará com que os dados sejam transmitidos mais rápidos entre cliente e servidor.

Comment: Editei melhor a pergunta, para melhor enteder o que estou fazendo.
E ve se realmente essa é a forma correta.

Answer (score 2):

Você não tem a opção de requisitar somente um elemento como fez (a não ser que crie uma tratativa no lado do servidor).

No entanto, para não precisar disso, você pode selecionar diretamente pelo front-end, utilizando o jQuery:

```
$.get('editaagenda.php', function (data) {
  var $root = $(data);
  $('.read_content').html($('#read_content', $root).html());
});
```

Comment: Não retornou o resultado esperado.
Vou testar aqui criar um novo arquivo apenas com as informações requeridas. Como o amigo sugeriu acima para ver.